# Flask/Flask-restful: Force/correct/override incorrect content-type header for POST requests

Tags: flask, flask-restful

I have a problem with an closed source application that is sending 
an incorrect content type in the header.

I receive data as "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

I should receive it as "content-type: application/json"

Below is the flask server code, using Flask and Flask-restful

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource, request

TEST_PROXY = "0.0.0.0"
TEST_PROXY_PORT = 1885
DEBUG = True

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class TEST(Resource):

    def get(self, queue, subqueue):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('m', type=str, help='A message')
        args = parser.parse_args()

        TEST_queue = f'/{queue}/{subqueue}'
        message = args.get('m')

        return {'type': 'GET',
            'message': args.get('m'),
            'queue': TEST_queue}

    def post(self, queue, subqueue):
        TEST_queue = f'/{queue}/{subqueue}'

        # here is the problem
        # because of the incorrect header
        # the returned data is empty.

        message = request.data


        return {'type': 'POST',
           'message-length': len(message),
            'queue': TEST_queue}

api.add_resource(TEST, '/TEST/<string:queue>/<string:subqueue>')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=DEBUG, host=TEST_PROXY, port=TEST_PROXY_PORT)
```

Sending

```
POST http://localhost:1885/TEST/sub/sub2
Content-Type: application/json

{"status": {"current_time": "now"}}
```

works. request.data is filled with the content

```
POST http://localhost:1885/TEST/sub/sub2
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

{"status": {"current_time": "now"}}
```

works, but requests.data is now empty, instead, the data has been parsed and is no longer available in unchanged form.

Since the sender is closed source, fixing the problem on that side is not possible at short notice.

Is there a way of overriding the incorrect content type for POST requests/this request so I can access the original posted data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.get_data()` instead of `request.data`.

From [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request):

> `data` Contains the incoming request data as string in case it came with a mimetype Werkzeug does not handle.

and

> `get_data(cache=True, as_text=False, parse_form_data=False)` This reads the buffered incoming data from the client into one bytestring. By default this is cached but that behavior can be changed by setting cache to False.
>
> Usually it’s a bad idea to call this method without checking the content length first as a client could send dozens of megabytes or more to cause memory problems on the server.

But it would be better to check value in `request.content_type` and get data from `request.json` and `request.form`.

Comment: Alas, no. `get_data(` also returns nothing because the stream has been used. `request.form`  contains data, but all double keys are lost and some brackets, too. (If your JSON has line feeds, only on bracket survives, the next equal line is dropped.) So it's not possible to recreate the original data from that.

Comment: @576i Could you provide reproducible request from sender? Maybe with curl or python requests